# How to remove a numeric value at specific position in a String

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove a numeric value from a specific position position. I have used a regex but it deletes every numeric value from the String.

I have these Strings:

```
Draft1(admin)
Draft2(adminn)
Draft21(admin23)
Draft112(admin211)
```

And I want these strings as:

```
Draft(admin)
Draft(adminn)
Draft(admin23)
Draft(admin211)
```

currently I've used regex:

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\d", "");
```

which replaces all the numeric values and I get something like:

```
Draft(admin)
```

Comment: `string.replaceFirst("\\d+(?=\\()", "");`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `String#replaceFirst` with regex like `(?i)(?<=Draft)\d+` to delete this digits:

```
name = name.replaceFirst("(?i)(?<=Draft)\\d+","");
```

Where:

`(?i)` makes regex caseinsensitive, so the Draft could be even DRAFT or draft

`(?<=Draft)` is lookbehind for `Draft` word, which asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is `Draft`

`\\d+` are one or more digit to be replaced

Comment: You are welcome) if the answer was helpful, you can accept it or upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=Draft)\\d+\\b
```

You can use this and replace by `empty string`.The `lookbehind` will make sure it replace only numbers after `Draft`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
class String111
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
String s1="Draft1(admin)";
String s2="Draft21(admin23)";

System.out.println(s1.substring(0,s1.indexOf('(')).replaceAll("\\d", "")+s1.substring(s1.indexOf('('),s1.length()));

System.out.println(s2.substring(0,s2.indexOf('(')).replaceAll("\\d", "")+s2.substring(s2.indexOf('('),s2.length()));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "Draft112(admin211)";
    name = name.replaceAll("\\d+(?=\\()","");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```